# Update query with sub-select

Tags: db2

x_addr_table1

```
Address_id,member_id,Primary,email1
7000012  56781    1     abcdef@gmail.com
7000013  56781    0     dummy@gmail.com
7000014  56781    0     abcdef@gmail.com
7000015  56782    1     mnopqr@gmail.com
7000016  56782    0     XYZXYZ@gmail.com
7000017  56782    0     mnopqr@gmail.com
```

I was trying to update emails in the above table where a members email is different is different from others.

I'm trying to achieve this by creating 2 temporary tables.

x_primary_email_table2

```
Address_id,member_id,priemail1
7000012  56781  abcdef@gmail.com
7000015  56782  mnopqr@gmail.com
```

x_profilepay_email_table3

```
Address_id,member_id,payemail1
7000013  56781  dummy@gmail.com
7000016  56782  XYZXYZ@gmail.com
```

Here is my update query :

```
update x_addr_table1 x_addr 
set email1=(
  select T2.priemail1 
  from x_primary_email_table2 T2 
  where T2.member_id=x_addr.member_id
)
where x_addr.address_id in (
  select T2.address_id from x_primary_email_table2 T2
) and x_addr.member_id in (
  select T2.member_id 
  from x_primary_email_table2 T2, x_profilepay_email_table3 t3 
  where t2.member_id=t3.member_id and   
  upper(T2.priemail1)!=upper(T3.payemail1)
)
```

I'm getting an error here :

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO
>   statement, or VALUES  INTO statement is more than one row. 
>   SQLSTATE=21000

Appreciate the help .

Answer (score 1):

You could do it directly on the source table

```
update x_addr_table1 x
   set email = (select email 
                  from x_addr_table1 
                 where member_ID = x.member_id  and primary = 1)
 where Primary = 0
   and email <> (select email 
                  from x_addr_table1 
                  where member_ID = x.member_id  and primary = 1)
```